# Attach winform scrollbar to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro, scrollbar

Just started develop an application in `c#` using `winforms` metro ui and I can't figure out how to use a metroscrollbar with a metro textbox. If i go under properties when selecting the textbox i can choose scrollbar but it shows the normal Windows form..

Please see the picture down below:
[image]

How can I use the Metro scrollbar instead of the normal scrollbar?

Comment: Are you using standard controls? I suppose there is a new class for  form itself. Your form should be derived from it. Or there might be a container control with such scrollbar, then simply use that control to host content.

Comment: The project does a very decent job emulating the Metro design style.  But there are practical limitations, the native Windows Edit control does not support altering or custom-painting the scrollbars.  So when you create a multi-line textbox then the scrollbar is going to look like it does in any other native Windows program.  You'll have to set the ScrollBars property to None.